# How can NSNotification be used to check a the status of an NSTask

Tags: cocoa

How can NSNotification be used to check a the status of an NSTask?  I know there are a couple of class methods inside the NSTask but don't really understand how to implement them in a Cocoa application.  Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task will be stuck when you won't read what it is sending on stdout/stderr. That's why you need to create pipes and set them using `setStandardOutput`.

Use `[NSFileHandle readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify]` and wait for `NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification`. It will give you all data in the callback.

Answer (score 5):

This blog post, [Better way to read from an NSTask](http://macosx.com/forums/software-programming-web-scripting/4522-better-way-read-nstask.html), describes how to use `NSNotification` to recieve notifications from an `NSTask`.

If you know that your task is not long-running, there is a simpler solution.  My answer to another SO question, [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app#412573), has an example of using `NSTask` that includes returning the status of the task w/o `NSNotification`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon, I have tried out the solution you gave but what's confusing me is when I write the code:

```
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
```

What is the output data can be return from the task?for my case the console window jus get stuck there and nothing have returned