# Darwin and ObjectiveC - How to call shell scripts from a Cocoa App?

Tags: objective-c

I need a good reference in how to get my hooks into Darwin. Basically I'd like to write an app the take care of some of the admin chores I do on my Macs. For example, moving new media to the backup server sorted by media type, pulling process info. Simple things like that. So basically I'd like to create a nifty GUI app that would call my shell scripts and give me the output of those scripts.

Is there anything equivilent to python's subprocess or C#'s Process library?

Links would suffice just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: My bad, question was already asked and answered here (Thanks Kent) -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app/696942#696942

Answer (score 3):

Will [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function to have the shell execute a command line:

```
system("path/to/my/shellscript.sh");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always the good old unix way to start processes: [fork](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/execve.2.html)

If you're planning to perform tasks that need administrator rights, you'll probably want to look into [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1). The [Security.framework](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004330) is used to get authorization from the keychain and start (unix) processes with extended privileges.