# Cocoa/ Objective-C Shell Command Line Execution

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, unix, command-line

This is probably a stupid question, but how can I execute a shell command from my Cocoa app?

I have the command as a string "command", but can easily manipulate data as needed.

There is no need to get a returned output value.

Comment: also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app/696942#696942

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) is pretty easy to do this with. For a synchronous call, you can use something like this fragment:

```
NSString *path = @"/path/to/executable";
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil];
[[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];
```

The `-waitUntilExit` call makes sure it finishes before proceeding. If the task can be asynchronous, you can remove that call and just let the NSTask do it's thing.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to run something and don't care about the output or return code (for example, you want to touch a file), you can just do

```
system("touch myfile.txt");
```

Easy as that.

Comment: Be very, very careful with `system` and `popen`. It's easy to introduce a vulnerability by letting characters through to the shell that it will consider special. NSTask and `fork`/`exec` are much safer.

Answer (score 3):

[NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Using the NSTask class, your program can run another program as a subprocess and can monitor that program’s execution.