# Add Login Item from Command Line Tool on OSX

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I just got an assignment where I need to add the running program to the login items for all users on OSX >= 10.5. The program is a command line tool and I am developing it in xcode. I found some ways to add login items, but they either run from a shell or use the cocoa framework.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I've done this from the command line:

```
defaults write loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{Path="/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app";}'
```

To execute a command like that from Obj-C, see this thread:

[Cocoa/ Objective-C Shell Command Line Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475182/cocoa-objective-c-shell-command-line-execution)