# MacOS Cocoa/Objective-C application calling a command line program (php) and getting its output. how?

Tags: php, cocoa, macos

I'd like to get pointed to a reference or guide on executing a command line program (namely the php interpreter) from a MacOS Cocoa/Objective-C application, and getting its output (namely the stdout from the php script execution)

If there's something about it in `http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/`, which I couldn't find, great! if not, from anywhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475182/cocoa-objective-c-shell-command-line-execution

Comment: You want `NSTask`. There are many, many questions about it on Stack Overflow, some of which with examples of how to read `stdout`.