# Get XML from system()

Tags: objective-c, xml

I have this shell command that return xml data.
I'm new to Objective-C. I want to load in some XML using the `system()` function.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475182/cocoa-objective-c-shell-command-line-execution

Comment: I know how to run the command. I just need to get the returned value and be able to use it in a Objective-C application I'm making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `system()` for that, because it doesn't return any data from the command to you. Instead, all of the program's output will go to the terminal.

The Cocoa way to do this is [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/).

You need to:

- use `setLaunchPath` and optionally `setArguments` to specify what program to run
- pass an `NSPipe` to `setStandardOutput`
- `launch` the program
- read from the pipe until you hit the end of the input