# Launch command line in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, command-line, command-line-arguments, nstask

I would like to exec this command line in objective-C in order to launch an app from another :

```
open -n myApp.app --args arg1 arg2
```

I managed to do it without arguments with :

```
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *myAppPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myApp.app",[fileMgr currentDirectoryPath] ];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:myAppPath];
```

But I can't figure out how to do it with arguments. Following [Cocoa/ Objective-C Shell Command Line Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475182/cocoa-objective-c-shell-command-line-execution) and [Launching an Mac App with Objective-C/Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048677/launching-an-mac-app-with-objective-c-cocoa) , I tried :

```
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myApp.app",[fileMgr currentDirectoryPath]];
    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arg1",@"arg2", nil];
    [[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];
```

I get the error :

```
*** NSTask: Task create for path '/path/to/app/myApp.app' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.
```

I precise that I need to launch it with NSTask for the waitUntilExit function. Indeed, I need the app which launches the other app to wait until the launched app exit.
Thanks!

Comment: you may achieve this using system(Const char *command) API .Do some research on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. In fact, it's not :

```
NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myApp.app",[fileMgr currentDirectoryPath]];
```

but :

```
NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp",[fileMgr currentDirectoryPath]];
```

So the final code is :

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp",[fileMgr currentDirectoryPath]];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arg1",@"arg2", nil];
[[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];
```