# objective c "say" command

Tags: objective-c, applescript, command

In applescript there is a say command. Is there something like this for objective c?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cocoa also has the `NSSpeechSynthesizer` class.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Speech/Speech.html)

Comment: Yep, in fact one of the first exercises in Hillegass (Cocoa programming for Mac OS X) is a simple GUI app that says whatever you type in the textfield, after clicking a button.

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone there is no way.  If you are talking about mac code, Cocoa has a class to do this (NSSpeechSynthesizer).

Code:

```
NSSpeechSynthesizer * syn = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[syn startSpeakingString:@"my string"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use NSTask to run the 'say' commandline program

[SO Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

Answer (score 0):

Are you switching to the windows environment?? If so, you can utilized the Speech SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(VS.85).aspx

Here is an example of how to implement it in C# (sorry, not that familiar with C, hopefully its helpful):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ssrinivas/TextToSpeechConversioninCSharp11222005060134AM/TextToSpeechConversioninCSharp.aspx

If you aren't switching to windows, hopefully there is a way to use the say SKD...

Comment: Given that he mentions Applescript and Objective-C, it seems extremely unlikely that he'd be using Windows or C#.