# Execute shell script from cocoa (obj.c) with response

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, bash, shell

I have something like:

```
- (NSString *)unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn:(NSString *)command
{
NSPipe *newPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *readHandle = [newPipe fileHandleForReading];

NSTask *unixTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[unixTask setStandardOutput:newPipe];
[unixTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[unixTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", command , nil]]; 
[unixTask launch];
[unixTask waitUntilExit];

NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return output;
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I call it when i click a button. If i remove the line with 'waitUntilExit' it works as expected, but only once. When it's there, it doesn't work.
I tried also some basic commands like 'ls' 'ping -c1 google.com' and stuff like that, but i can't get it to work somehow. If you have some different approach to run shell scripts in cocoa with receiving the response, please let me now. Thank you all :)

Comment: Hi, interesting - this code works well for me. However for some reason it messes with NSLog - and NSLog won't display anything for me, but when run directly from the console it will work as expected. I haven't changed your code in any way ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey, Kukosk. There’s a comment on [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask) about `NSLog()` issues when running an NSTask. The fix is to set a pipe for `stdin` before launching the task:

```
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
```

If you’re relying on `NSLog()` only to check whether the task has run, this might fix your problem. Alternatively, you could try to present `output` in your GUI instead of using `NSLog()`.

Comment: thanks @bavarious you saved my day! Wait, aren't you the same person in another NSTask thread??? :) God bless you...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't emptying the output buffers of the task.  You can't simply launch a task and `waitUntilDone` unless the task also emits an extremely small amount of data.

`waitUntilDone` will obviously not work at all with a task that never exits.

For a task that emits any quantity of output, you need to set it up such that the output is read as it is generated.  Typically, you use `readInBackgroundAndNotify` or a variant therein.

In any case, the top of the class description for `NSTask` has both links to the conceptual guide and to a series of examples that cover this.

Comment: So what do i have to do in general? Can u please post the working code with a bit explanation, please? It will really help! I am familiar with obj.c, but i was coding for the iOS platform, so some things i have never used are kinda new for me :) thank you for your response.

Comment: The NSTask documentation goes in depth on the subject, including extensive examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, there's a very important line in the docs you seem to have missed, one of those irritations that NextStep seems to like: "An NSTask object can only be run once. Subsequent attempts to run the task raise an error."

So, bag the wait, and add [unixTask release] before the return. When you want to run it again, remake the task.

NSTimer is like this.

Comment: OP is making a new task on each invocation to that method.  That isn't the problem (though you are correct in that said code is leaking the task).

Comment: He’d also be leaking the output string, except that I know for a fact he’s using garbage collection. Hey, Kukosk. =P

Comment: im using the gc ;) but i will release it since it'll work even if i use gc

Answer (score 0):

For different approaches to run shell scripts in Cocoa have a look at AMShellWrapper, PseudoTTY.app or OpenFileKiller!

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask