# Create NSTask for gdb

Tags: cocoa, nstask

I'm trying to create an NSTask that uses GDB to attach to a program, but my program just freezes after launching the task. Is this possible to do? Here is the code I'm using:

```
NSTask  *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/gdb"];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TestApp.app", nil];
[task setArguments:args];
[task launch];
NSLog(@"Launched.");

NSData *data = [[outPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
NSLog(@"Read data.");
```

I'm certain "TestApp.app" is in the correct location because I don't get "No such file or directory" errors. The console only prints "Launched." and the spinning beachball just continues for over a minute until I kill the run. Any ideas what could make this work?

Comment: I suggest you read the following posts on Cocoa Dev Central: [Wrapping UNIX Commands](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000025.php) and [Wrapping UNIX Commands Part II](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000031.php).

Comment: Does your gdb NSTask detach immediately after executing the command or does it create a persistent session (like in terminal)?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

- It’s wise to [set a pipe for standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652134/execute-shell-script-from-cocoa-obj-c-with-response/4658755#4658755). There are some situations, particularly when `NSLog()` is called, that end up hanging `NSTask`.
- If you send `-readDataToEndOfFile` to the standard output handle, your thread will pause until the task has finished executing. This is particularly bad if that code is running on the main thread — no user interface changes or application events will be processed, which most likely ends up beachballing the application. Use the `…inBackground…` methods instead.
- You’re not sending data to standard input. If `gdb` doesn’t receive any input, it waits indefinitely until it receives a command.