# Execute terminal command top from a Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to execute top and get the result in order to know how much memory is used by a process.

First, I want to execute a terminal command. I use code from this question
[Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app/696942#696942)

I tried with uptime and it worked flawlessly.

But, when I tried to use top instead of uptime, i get the following error:

**Error opening terminal: unknown.**

Or, top is in /usr/bin/top, I don't know why it refuses to use it.

Here is my code:

```
   NSTask *task;
   task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/top"];

   /*NSArray *arguments;
   arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"foo", @"bar.txt", nil];
   [task setArguments: arguments];*/

   NSPipe *pipe;
   pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
   [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

   NSFileHandle *file;
   file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

   [task launch];

   NSData *data;
   data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

   NSString *string;
   string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [label setStringValue: string];

   [string release];
   [task release];
```

Second question: the thing I am trying to do is to know how much memory is used by Google Chrome. 
Because it uses a process for each tab, it's difficult to know how much memeroy in total it uses.

Problem 1: top changes its value every second, how can I get a value?
Problem 2: how can I search in the result of top in order to find only the processes I want (given that I know their names).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that commands like top needs a **terminal** (= window to interact with) to execute.

This means they need **a real window context**, because they display the results dynamically in the window (clearing the window, displaying the output of "top" in the whole terminal window, and more important, update the display every N seconds, redrawing the whole terminal window)

So as commands like `top` need a real "Terminal", this is why, when using `top` with `NSTask`, it throw "Error opening terminal".

---

You may instead check in the manual page of top (`man top`) if there is an option to avoid dynamic paging of the command and instead output a single shot (without using ncurse and the terminal dynamic display) directly on stdout (maybe try `top -l 1` -- Don't have my Mac here to try myself and confirm).

Or a better solution is probably to dig around commands like `ps` (or others?) instead of `top` that will give you the same info but directly on stdout instead of as a dynamic display in a terminal.

Comment: NSTask does not provide a shell.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know top needed a window to execute, now it makes sense. I will use ps or a variation of ps.

Now the harassing task is to crawl through the enormous result given to sort out the information I need...

Comment: Tks for perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, use the arguments for top. For example

```
top -l 1
```

This will give one set of output.

Hence in the code:

```
NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-l 1", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];
```

This will successfully execute the NSTask.

Answer (score 1):

For non interactive operations with process information, I would use [`ps`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html) instead of `top`.