# Cocoa Objective-C shell script from application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shell

I have an application that I'm creating and would like to run a shell scripts from within it. One of the scripts creates a .plist file, and the other does a patch on a binary file. The reason why want to do this with a shell script is because I know that it works for the two things that I need it for. I'm sure there's a way to do it with Objective-C/Cocoa although I don't know how, so any recommendations on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You mean MacOS or? You can forget that with iOS, tho you can easily create plists and patch binaries directly from obj-c (in the writable directory only).

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, it's for OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use `NSTask`. `NSTask` is a system for running any Terminal command. Here's how you could use it to execute a shell script:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/path/to/script/sh"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"yourScript.sh", nil]];
[task setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

[task launch];
[task release];
```

That would run the command `/path/to/script/sh yourScript.sh`. If you need any arguments for your script, you can add them to the array of arguments. The standard output will redirect all output to a pipe object, which you can hook into if you want to output to a file. The reason we need to use another `NSPipe` for input is to make `NSLog` work right instead of logging to the script.

If you want more info on how `NSTask` works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412573/465378).

Comment: Thank you for the awesome example. Is there a way to compile the script into the binary?

Comment: @Buxme: You can add the shell script to your project and get the path to it with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scriptName" ofType:@"sh"]`. Then just use that path for the first argument, and it should run just fine.

Comment: Will this cause the terminal to open to execute the script, or will this cause the application in objective-c itself to run the script without opening the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know is [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
It's just like a terminal command from where you can call your bash script.

Comment: Even better than a terminal command, since you pass the arguments in an array and your program runs the task directly; with no shell involved, you don't need to worry about shell escaping.

Comment: Cool. Do you have by chance have an example? Also, will it not be obvious that my application is calling a shell script, or is this not really even a shell script? BTW - I would want the script to be compiled into the binary.

Comment: @Buxme: What do you mean by “obvious”? The user can't tell that you're running another process unless they look in Activity Monitor.

Comment: @PeterHosey — yes, that would define obvious.