# Running compiled native code inside an iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a compiled program I wrote in native c, which i can run on the my Iphone using 
terminal and the command "./myCApp"

Is there a way to launch it through Code?

I've tried System("./myCApp") 
or popen("./myCApp","r+)

and both didn't work.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app) answer your question? EDIT: Actually, nevermind, that seems to be Mac only.

Comment: Just guessing - maybe if you save it as part of application bundle? Or if that not works: you move it from bundle to /documents and try from there...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can launch a code in device programmatically unless it has some url scheme.

Comment: actually you can in jailbroken devices

Comment: I think it's possible in jailebroken. mine is.  but how??
@Vin ?

Comment: @zaxy78 what are you looking for? executing your native code inside another application or just run this code on the device?

Comment: just run this on the device.
execute and leave. that's all