# How do I join a wireless network programmatically under OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, wifi

C or C++ preferred. This is not an Objective-C project.

I already know the SSID. There may be WPA2 security on the network. I need to join from a specific interface (e.g. eth2) in case the machine has more than one wireless interface.

I realize that there are various commandline tools out there (e.g. the ones provided in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481005/get-wireless-ssid-through-shell-script-on-mac-os-x)), but I'd like to join the network without exec'ing external dependencies that may or may not be on the machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you can do the following:

```
execlp("networksetup", "networksetup", "-setairportnetwork", "$INTERFACE", "$SSID", "$PASSWORD", NULL);
```

Comment: Just a note that I had to add a NULL to the end of the argument list to avoid receiving a `Missing sentinel in function call` warning.

Answer (score 2):

The [`networksetup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) tool *will* be on the machine, as it's part of the standard operating system. There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

**From the Terminal, try this :**

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork $INTERFACE $SSID $PASSWORD
```

Or, **if you want to integrate it in a Cocoa/Objective-C app** :

check my code here for `runCmd` ( [(Mac) Creating Xcode app that executes shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082162/mac-creating-xcode-app-that-executes-shell-scripts/10082188#10082188) ) on how to run an external command with `NSTask` and `NSPipe`.

In that case, you should call it like :

```
[self runCmd:@"/usr/sbin/networksetup" 
    withArgs:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-setairportnetwork",
                                              @"INTERFACE",
                                              @"SSID",
                                              @"PASS",
                                              nil]];
```

---

> but I'd like to join the network without exec'ing external
>   dependencies that may or may not be on the machine.

It **will** be there... :-)