# How do you run the rails command from a cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, cocoa, rvm

I've been stuck on this one for a while. I'm trying to run a rails shell command from my cocoa application to create a news rails app. When I run

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails new projectname
```

I'm able to create a new project. But if I run something like this

```
NSString *path = @"~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails";
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ new ~/Desktop/testapp", path];
system([script UTF8String]);
```

or this

```
- (IBAction)buildProject:(NSButton *)sender 
{
NSString *path = @"~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails";
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"new", @"~/Desktop/testapp", nil];

NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:path];
[task setArguments:args];
[task launch];
}
```

I get the following error

```
/Users/dylanross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails:7:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/cli (LoadError)
from /Users/dylanross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails:7
```

Comment: RVM performs magic on your shell that is missing when you do your call. I am not 100% sure, but you might get it by executing `/usr/bin/env ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails new projectname` instead.

Comment: As @Amadan says you probably need to initialize your ruby environment somehow and by the fact that `system` (which probably uses a non-interactive shell) did not work i guess the environment is setup in your `~/.bashrc` file. You could try `sh -i -c ".../rails new bla"`.

Comment: this answer run OK on 10.8.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I was using `/bin/sh` as launchPath.

Try this swift code.

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
let fileToRun = "/Users/johndoe/Desktop/testapp/app.rb"
task.arguments = ["-l", "rvm-auto-ruby", fileToRun]
let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()
```