# Execute SSH Command on remote Linux Machine using Native Mac App. (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linux, ssh

I have a Mac Native app written with Xcode. I want to execute some SSH command using that application on remote servers and get the result back to user.

Is there any library/Framework exist for that? Is that possible?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I need to execute that on Remote machine!

Comment: No, it will run `ssh`, which will (can) connect to a remote machine and run commands there.  See the answer below for a fleshed out version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use the `NSTask` class to execute an `ssh` command.

The following code was adapted from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app).

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/ssh"]; // Tell the task to execute the ssh command
[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"<user>:<hostname>", @"<command>"]]; // Set the arguments for ssh to contain only your command. If other configuration is necessary, see the ssh(1) man page.

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading]; // This file handle is a reference to the output of the ssh command

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // This string now contains the entire output of the ssh command.
```

Comment: This will execute the <command> on local machine (Mac OS) but I need to connect to a remote machine which running Linux.

Comment: So sorry, I forgot an argument! There needs to be the user and hostname.