# How to get network stats using "nettop" inside of objective c code in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, process

I need to get how many bytes were sent and received by particular process/application in OS X programatically.

There is command line "nettop" which do that. I want to launch it in my code and return result into buffer (e.g. NSString) and then parse it.

As example I used the following code from topic: 
[Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/nettop"];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"result returned:\n%@", string);
```

The problem is that it returns empty string. How to solve the following problem?

P.S. If you know/have example code how to get count of received and sent bytes by each process please provide.

Comment: I also want to know "how to get count of received and sent bytes by each process". @sergio do you have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the best way to get network stats from macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW: Did you took a look to console?
I'm receiving: `Error opening terminal: unknown.`

This message is printed, because you are trying to run `nettop` in interactive mode.
But it looks like `nettop` do not support non-interactive mode. Because with `top` everything runs just fine, using fallowing setup:

```
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/nettop"];
[task setArguments:@[@"-l1"]];
```

According to Google `-l1` runs it in non-interactive mode. With `top` everything runs just fine, but with `nettop` it doesn't work.

Comment: So you just added:     [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/top"];
    [task setArguments:@[@"-l1"]];
and it returns result into "string"?

Comment: Exactly. But not right away, I need to wait 1-2s, or maybe even more.