# Cocoa Setting Terminal Exit Code Variable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to be able to set a terminal variable; basically what I want to do is assign my own exit code through my app.  My research finds that [NSTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app) maybe the way to do this, but I can't say for sure how to go on about this since I know for one, I do not know if I can have a `setLaunchPath:`.

Here is an example of what I would type in the terminal:

> `bash-3.2$ $(exit 15); echo ${?};`
>
> `15`

Sorry if the question doesn't sound very technical.  Please ask if you need clarifications.  Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a good fit with a Cocoa application.  Or are you considering a Foundation command-line tool?

First, it's not typical to invoke a Cocoa application from a command-line shell.  If you do, it's most common to do so using the `/usr/bin/open` command, which is not normally synchronous and so doesn't convey the app's exit status to the shell.

Second, the process which exits does not directly set the shell variable.  It exits with a status code and that's stored in the kernel.  The shell then obtains that status code from the kernel and sets its own variable.  It is not generally possible for one process to set an environment variable (or any other state) in another process (other than one it spawns itself) without that other process's cooperation.

Third, a Cocoa application typically quits using `-[NSApplication terminate:]`.  That doesn't provide a way to tell the framework what value to use as the exit status code.  `NSApplicationMain()`, which is what's typically called by the app's `main()` function, is documented to never return and to call `exit()`.  The documentation suggests that it may specify some meaningful status code – "If you want to determine why the application exited, you should look at the result code from the exit function instead." – but not what that might be nor any way to influence it.

You might call `exit()` yourself from the `-applicationWillTerminate:` method of your application delegate.  That way, you get to specify the status code.  I'm not sure, though, if that might break any final cleanup that Cocoa might do.  For example, if you have promised some data to the pasteboard, Cocoa requests that you provide it before your application terminates.  I'm not sure if that occurs before or after `-applicationWillTerminate:` (probably before).  That delegate call is in response to the application object posting the `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notification and there may be other observers of that notification.  The order in which observers get notified is not specified, so the app delegate is not necessarily the last thing that would get it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your lengthy response.  I will research into your suggestions further.  

The reason I would like to be able to set exit variable is because I'm doing a pre-login App that launches via a LoginHook script. Depending on the output of the App (its exit code), I'd like to continue the login process (if exit 0) or do something else (I'm thinking stop the login process at this point, or logout, or restart).  Right now, I can't think of another method other than using the app's exit code.  I know for sure now that your `exit()` suggestion got me to where I want to be.