# how to join two flv files in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ffmpeg, video-processing

i've parsed a video web and got the flv files for the video, but the files are seperated, so i must join them together, i know if i use ffmpeg, it should be easy just like `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.flv`  ,but as i'm writing a mac software, i must write it in objective-c.i could't found any document (or sdk) to read so it's hard for me to begin.

so ,how to join them in objective-c code? do i need to pull the ffmpeg project down to my project?if it is necessary, what is the next step?

Comment: [you could always use a C++ wrapper, and then you can use your C++ library and code.](http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects)

Comment: you could use [NSTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

Comment: @Mike i will have a try on mixing them together, thanx。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly a comprehensive answer, but should get you started:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task setLaunchPath:@"<whatever your path to ffmpeg is>"];
// I'm taking your word for the arguments...
[task setArguments:@[@"-f", @"concat", @"-i", @"mylist.txt", @"-c", @"copy", @"output.flv"]];

[task launch];
```

You may want to go further by setting up a pipe and file handle so that you can get stdout or stderr.

And yes, you'll need to include `ffmpeg` in your project.

Comment: if i've include `ffmpeg` into my project, what's the path to my ffmpeg? [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]?

Comment: Put ffmpeg where you keep your source files. From the 'Editor' menu in Xcode, add a Copy Files build phase, then add ffmpg there, specifying that it goes in Executables. Use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"ffmpeg"]` to get the path.