# Objective-C - How to convert file path to shell conform file path

Tags: objective-c, shell, nsstring

I want to execute a shell command (I want to `touch` a file). I use `system("shell command")` to execute the command.

For example I want to touch the file at path `/Users/username/New Folder/`. Now I need to convert the `NSString` in a format that is conform to shell commands like `/Users/username/New\ Folder`.

Is there any method that does a conversion like this?

NOTE: It is NOT just replacing a whitespace with `\`. If you have a special character in the path like `/Users/username/Folder(foo)/` the "shell path" looks like this `/Users/username/Folder\(foo\)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert the path, you can surround it in single quotes. Just use:

```
touch 'path'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the parameters that contain spaces with " " marks.

```
touch "/Users/username/New Folder/"
```

At least this works at the shell prompt

Comment: Single quotes are better, double quotes don't prevent shell expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `system`. It's insecure and unpredictable. Surrounding the string with quotes is not sufficient.

Use the [execve style functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app) instead. They are simple and secure.