# How do I run a packaged shell script file in xcode? (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, cocoa, shell

I have made a shell script file and I want to be able to run it from within the application. Obviously, if I wanted to distribute the app, I would need to package the .sh file (which I have done) but I am not sure how to run the packaged .sh file.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Look at [NSTask](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSTask_Class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=2AgWVPu9DonkaM3ngPgO&usg=AFQjCNExYvCAo4XewShPDs8SBK39W0qKXg&sig2=jO7_2SYYqY8CHqSDYEqL-A&bvm=bv.75097201,d.d2s)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right answer, because it contains only an suggestion and not the solution, but the following could really help you:

Check the [platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) application.

*It creates native Mac OS X applications from interpreted scripts such as shell scripts or Perl, Ruby and Python programs.* - e.g. create an wrapper where inside is the shell script, so you can check how it is done.

Moreover it is [opensource](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus), so you can check the source, how to do this correctly and for more insights.