# Opening OS X Apple Maps with specific coordinates from Cocoa command line tool

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nstask

I am trying to launch the native Maps app and show a specific coordinate in OS X from my command line tool.

I've found three options:

- Use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];`
- Use the `open` command and pass a formatted URL and let the system figure it out.
- Use `NSTask` to launch Maps.app with the URL.

I tried the first one:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@&ll=%f,%f", user[@"realName"], geo.latitude, geo.longitude];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

(where it results in a perfectly valid string)

But it doesn't work. It just does nothing. Nothing opens, no errors, no warnings. Then I went to the second option. I couldn't figure out how to do the second, so I've turned up to `NSTask`. I've found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/412573/811405 and I've passed this URL as argument: `http://maps.apple.com/?q=Example&ll=12.345,23.456` but I'm getting:

[image]

How can I open maps with a specific point from a Cocoa command line tool?

Comment: So, you tried something like `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=Example&ll=12.345,23.456"]]` and it didn't work? Because it works here. Show **actual code** with actual values and tell us exactly what happened.

Comment: @KenThomases see my updated question

Comment: And why did you not show the resulting "perfectly valid string"? Does it, for example, have a space in it, as a user's real name might? That's not a valid URL string. Have you tried putting the result of `[NSURL URLWithString:url]` in a separate variable and examining it? I bet it's `nil`. Use `NSURLComponents` to construct URLs piecemeal.

Comment: @KenThomases I can't post the exact string because this is a public website and it's people's name with home coordinates. I've tried what you said, and yes, it is `nil`. Yes, user's name has spaces, but I thought Cocoa would just escape it to `%20` seamlessly. I'll try escaping it manually.

Comment: @KenThomases yep, that was it. I've escaped it with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` and it worked. could you please post your comment regarding the space inside the string as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your URL string was not valid because it had a space in it. Therefore, `[NSURL URLWithString:url]` was returning `nil`.

Do not use string formatting to build URLs. Don't build potentially-invalid URL strings and then try to fix it by calling `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`. You can't properly percent-escape encode whole URL strings. Each component has different valid/invalid characters that need to be escaped.

The best approach is to use `NSURLComponents` to build your URL from parts.

If you can't do that, use `-stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` on each component of the URL before concatenating them together. For the query component, you would use `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some [documentation about Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1) that Apple provides.

And when I typed in http://maps.apple.com/?ll=12.345,23.456, the maps app opens up with a blank beige screen (because the coordinates appears to be in the middle of a desert in Sudan).

From the command line, I was able to do [`open "http://maps.apple.com/?q=Cupertino`](http://maps.apple.com/?q=Cupertino) and that works great.