# how to write properly terminal command in objective c

Tags: objective-c, terminal

I have to run the command to kill the process and the command is `kill pgrep -f /dev`,I know that to run the command `NSTask` is used 
but how to run the above command with these special arguments and the pgrep -f /dev is in `` 
I have tried this code

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
 [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/kill"];
 [task setArguments:@[@"`",@"pgrep",@"-f",@"/dev",@"`" ];
 [task launch];
```

Please tell how to write it properly,I know I have given arguments wrong.
Thanks,
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app

Comment: I followed this link but still face the problem , how can i write a command sudo kill `pgrep -f /dev` using NSTask ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to lie in misunderstanding how a command line is handled. When you type the line:

```
kill `pgrep -f /dev`
```

you are typing to your *shell*, which is probably `bash` but could be `tcsh` etc. The back quotes (`) are a shell feature; the shell will arrange to run both commands and take the output of `pgrep` and pass it as arguments to `kill`.

In your code you are attempting to execute `kill` and pass it as arguments the back quoted `pgrep` command. This won't work, `kill` knows nothing about back quotes, that is a shell feature...

So read the shell documentation (`man sh`) and you will discover that you can pass a shell command line as a single argument to the shell command itself - you can try it in the terminal yourself. Having figured that out you can use your `NSTask` code to run the shell, passing it your command line.

HTH