# change proxy on mac osx programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, proxy, ip-address

How does one programmatically change proxy settings on a mac osx. I am fluent in ios, and since mac os programming is similar there shouldn't be much problems with it. However I lack the logic needed to create proxy  changes programmatically.. Manual tweaking is extremely easy. This is the network tab in System Preferences I am after:

[image]

What I have tried:

```
let dynamicStore: SCDynamicStoreRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "setProxy" as CFString, nil, nil)!
let updated = SCDynamicStoreSetValue(dynamicStore, "HTTPProxy" as CFStringRef, "111.222.333.1") // updated is false, indicating unsuccessful operation
```

Also tried this, but the dictionary returned is read only

```
let dynamicStore: SCDynamicStoreRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "myFunc" as 

    CFString, nil, nil)!

    let proxyDict = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(dynamicStore)

    if let proxyDict = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(dynamicStore) as NSDictionary? {
        if let port = proxyDict["HTTPPort"] as? Int {
            print("HTTPPort:", port)
            proxyDict["HTTPPort"] = 8088; // can't do that
        }
    }
```

I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23469/33248), here is a sample script:

```
e=$(networksetup -getsocksfirewallproxy wi-fi | grep "No")

if [ -n "$e" ]; then
  echo "Turning on proxy"
  networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi on
else
  echo "Turning off proxy"
  networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi off
fi
```

It swiches (on/off) the SOCKS proxy for the user's Wi-Fi connection.

You can use this idea to make the script for your needs. You can implement your desired logic in a bash script like that or in Cocoa.

- Use `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` to list all connections.
- Use `networksetup -setwebproxy` to setup proxy for a particular connection.

For example, here's my Terminal output:

```
$ networksetup -listallnetworkservices
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
MBBEthernet
Wi-Fi
Wi-Fi Modem Yota 4G LTE
Bluetooth PAN
Thunderbolt Bridge
iPhone

$ networksetup -setwebproxy some bad args
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

$ networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi 1.2.3.4 8080
```

The last command gave the empty stdout, it means success.

See also [`man networksetup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html).

[How to execute a shell command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app).

The above commands executed from Terminal app asked for authorization. I'm sorry I'm not sure if you can leave it "as is" (just launch your `NSTask`, OS X will do the rest), or you need to obtain proper credentials via [SFAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFoundationFramework/Classes/SFAuthorization_Class/index.html) before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy` would do the trick, but even after you successfully changed the dictionary, `SCDynamicStoreSetMultiple` just has no effect.