# download latest project from git and replace in project through ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, shell

My ios app will be dependent upon external framework/library available at git.I want to check the available version on git and download if required and replace in project's folder path.Everything needs to b done on app launch or say application did finish launching.

Please suggest how can this be implemented in objective c. Can it be done through running shell script? If yes then how. please please help.

Also, i go through these links and tried but there is error for NSTask undeclared identifier. 
[Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app/696942#696942)

Comment: This is not possible, as the framework has to be up on build time.

Comment: @shallowThought what it means- framework needs to be up on build time?

Comment: How I understood you want to pull a library used by your application in  `application did finish launching`. Right?

Comment: o Great. i might be thinking that why there is need to run command pod install everytime. so Suggest me if it happen automatically then it doesnot need of all those command. :)

Comment: @shallowThought Yes! I want to check if there is any updated library available on git then download and replace in folder.

Comment: I probably get this wrong. I'm out :-)