# Running a command when a Button is pressed in a Cocoa GUI (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How can I have a shell command run when a user clicks a Button in my Cocoa GUI?

I would like to have a button that when pressed, runs the command caffeinate to keep the computer awake.

I do not know how to code this function and have googled.

Comment: you may ask this question to google by adding more and more keywords to your search query like: macos run shell command objective C

by the way check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app

Comment: The Cocoa way is to create a [IOPMAssertion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1557134-iopmassertioncreatewithname?language=objc). The shell detour is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You run command line commands via `NSTask`.  You create an NSTask, set the path to the command you want to run, set up the arguments and then call the task.  If you google how to use `NSTask` I'm sure you'll find some example code.

Here is the Apple Developer documentation for `NSTask`:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask?language=occ

Comment: and I see that the comment you received pointing to another stack overflow answer has the code you need in detail.