# how to break string into array in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

i need to break a string into an array,
 as "2 + 3" should be as "2","+","3"
even "2+3" should be "2","+","3"

Comment: you might look this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

As long as the format is consistent (always a space between numbers and signs), NSArray's [-componentsSeparatedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) will work for you. If there's a possibility the string will appear like "2+3" or even "2 +3" you could try removing all whitespace characters with [-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:) then using [-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:) with the sign characters you expect.

Comment: You could probably just use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` by itself in most cases.

Comment: Probably, but if you're looking for neat divisions with no spaces (ie, not " +" or "+ " but only "+" then you'll still have to get rid of the whitespace (before with one string is neater/easier than after with an array of strings).