# Extracting a small segment of NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an array and the contents look something like this:

```
    "user/01453303276519456080/state/com.google/starred",
    "user/01453303276519456080/state/com.google/broadcast",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/comics",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/General News",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/iPhone Related News",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/Programming",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/Sports",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/Tech News",
    "user/01453303276519456080/label/Tutorials",
    "user/01453303276519456080/state/com.blogger/blogger-following"
```

I want to extract only the last words after "/" (e.g. General News, Programming, etc) The unique id after user/ will not be constant.

Can someone give me an idea to implement this?

Cheers,
iSEE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lastPathComponent` API of NSString over each strings of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the lastPathComponent API solved it. Since you answered it before Sven, I mark this the correct answer....

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `lastPathComponent` method of `NSString`. This should give you exactly what you want. If you  need the other parts too you can use the method `componentsSeperatedByString:` or use a `NSScanner`.

Comment: If you need to break up the string by the / delimiter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c which has a good, quick example.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
for(int i=0;i<[yourArray count];i++)
{
  NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
  string=[yourArray objectAtIndex:i];       
  tempArray=[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
  //use tempArray

}
```

now tempArray having all strings at different indexes, fetch them according to you

Comment: no need to allocate a mutable array object, and then throw it away. the object you allocated is never used again

Comment: @user102008, i am making NSMutableArray because you cant call objectAtIndex and other methods on NSArray.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0;i<[myArray count];i++)
{
  NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
  string=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
  NSArray *arr=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
  tempArray=[arr objectAtIndex:([arr count]-1)];

}
```

Now this tempArray contains the last components as u want

Hope it will help u!

Comment: wow, this is terrible. `tempArray` is declared as an `NSMutableArray` but then you assign a string to it