# how to split strings in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, stringtokenizer

How to split a string in objective-C? I am working on an short application that contains a date picker. I do display date get it from date picker and display it through a label.

My main question is that how can I split the the date in to three separate strings?
any one has idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) or [`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to split the string, or use [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar) to extract the pieces of the date you're interested in.

Answer (score 9):

Use something like `[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]`. You will get an NSArray of separated strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you can format date into specific format using NSDateFormatter and then convert NSDate into NSString. You can extract components from date string using componentsSeparatedByString.

```
NSDate *myDate = datePicker.date;//if you are getting date from date picker

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMM d, hh:mm aa"];//you can use any date format also
NSString *myDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
```

You can get array of string by using this method and you can use string tokenizer according to your dateformat.for example "," string tokenizer.

```
[myDateString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to split the date into separate components:

```
NSDate *inputDate = [NSDate date];  //assign the value selected from date picker 
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* componentObj = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:inputDate];
NSInteger day = componentObj.day;
NSInteger month = componentObj.month;
NSInteger year = componentObj.year;
```