# iPhone : How to separate string like "ListName|Definition|Answer"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am getting string in the following format.

```
ListName|Definition|Answer
```

And How want to separate it like :

```
String1 : ListName

String2 : Definition

String3 : Answer
```

Here, this words can be deffer as per the change in value.

So at any other point it may be like `Hey|Name|Bye`.

But `|` is always in the string.

And Is it Possible to count number of `|` in the string ?

How do I separate it ?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c?

Comment: Is it possible to count number of `|` in the string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can separate it like :

```
NSString *string = @"ListName|Definition|Answer";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
```

now you have an array like:

```
chunk[0] = ListName
chunk[1] = Definition
chunk[2] = Answer
```

Hope it helps you....

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is built into the NSString class. The documentation for the class can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

The method to use would be.

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator

//An example of this in action
NSString *exampleString = @"Test|some|strings";

NSArray *separatedStrings = [exampleString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

At this point you can do whatever you would like with each string in the array such as iterating over it or accessing a specific string in the sequence.

I've included an example of iterating over the elements returned for reference.

```
//This for example is a nice use of the NSArray enumeration
//Much easier than the standard for loop with multiple parameters
for(NSString *aComponent in separatedStrings) {
   NSLog(@"A piece is: %@", aComponent);
   //Do something with each string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
NSArray *comps = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
NSString *listName = [comps objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *definition = [comps objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *answer = [comps objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: I think the 'NSString *answer = [comps objectAtIndex:3];' should be 'NSString *answer = [comps objectAtIndex:2];' :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is the entire code:

NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: array];

```
for(int i=0; i<[mutableArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strData = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",strData);
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

build an array for your input string

```
  NSArray *strArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
```

and then fill all the nsstrings from this array.