# Separating a single string into two Different Strings in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string, nsstring

I am just starting off with Objective-C and iphone app dev, i'm trying to design a calculator app, the logic i have used is this :
when the user clicks any button i take the title of the button by
[sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] method and then go on appending it onto a string(NSString *result).
say the user enters 123+456 , then in my string i will have "123+456", now i want two strings "123" and "456" so that i can add them by [result intValue] method.

So my question is, how do i get these two separate strings ("123" & "456")?

An example code with suitable methods would be very helpful.

Comment: To support `( )` and operator precedence you should look at parsing the input into tokens and using a grammar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSString * mystring = @"123+456";
NSArray * array = [mystring componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
NSString * str1 = [array objectAtIndex:0]; //123
NSString * str2 = [array objectAtIndex:1]; //456
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this at [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Found this at http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString (useful link):

```
NSString *string = @"oop:ack:bork:greeble:ponies";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
```

Hope this helps!

Adam

```
NSString *string = @"123+456";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"+"];

int res = [[chunks objectAtIndex:0] intValue]+[[chunks objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

Comment: the "objectAtIndex" method was missing, but i think u expected me to figure that out :p, which ofcourse i couldn't as i'm just in the learning phase. Neway, i appreciate your taking valuable time out to think about an answer and also ofc for answering. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* yourTwoStrings = [@"123+456" componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate strings by using `NSString`s `componentsSeparatedByString:`

```
NSString *calculation = @"1235+4362";
NSArray *results = [calculation componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);
```

If you are attempting to implement a calculator you may want to familiarize yourself with [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) as you will find trying to create a simple calculator will be a bit more challenging than expected..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the postfix and algo suggestion. But the thing is that i wanna do it without using any pushing-popping mechanism i.e a stack. If my efforts don't yield success, i'll definately go with the postfix method :), thanks