# Separate 1 NSString into two NSStrings by whiteSpace

Tags: iphone, nsstring, whitespace

I have an `NSString` which initially looked like `<a href="http://link.com"> LinkName</a>`. I removed the html tags and now have an `NSString` that looks like

```
http://Link.com   SiteName
```

how can I separate the two into different `NSString`s so I would have

```
http://Link.com
```

and

```
SiteName
```

I specifically want to show the `SiteName` in a label and just use the `http://Link.com` to open in a `UIWebView` but I can't when it is all one string. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *s = @"http://Link.com   SiteName";
NSArray *a = [s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"http: '%@'", [a objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"site: '%@'", [a lastObject]);
```

NSLog output:

```
http: 'http://Link.com'
site: 'SiteName'
```

Bonus, handle a site name with an embedded space with a RE:

```
NSString *s = @"<a href=\"http://link.com\"> Link Name</a>";
NSString *pattern = @"(http://[^\"]+)\">\\s+([^<]+)<";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:nil];

NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult = [regex firstMatchInString:s options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
NSString *http = [s substringWithRange:[textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1]];
NSString *site = [s substringWithRange:[textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:2]];

NSLog(@"http: '%@'", http);
NSLog(@"site: '%@'", site);
```

NSLog output:

```
http: 'http://link.com'
site: 'Link Name'
```

Comment: yes your right it works on some "siteName" but some are spaced as well like "Site Name"  so I am running into another issue... but I can use some dirty coding to get around it if theres no other way

Comment: You are probably better off using a Regular expression.

Comment: Thank you @CocoaFu I appreciate the help! For now I just used object at index 1 and last object to get what I needed but I will look into the Regular Expressions.. it seems more feasible.

Answer (score 2):

NSString has a method with the signature:

```
componentsSeparatedByString:
```

It returns an array of components as its result.  Use it like this:

```
NSArray *components = [myNSString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

[components objectAtIndex:0]; //should be SiteName
[components objectAtIndex:1]; // should be http://Link.com
```

Good luck.

Comment: Actually that won't get the site if there is more than one space character separation the components.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I knew it was a simple as a few lines of code just couldn't figure how to get them... both these answers will work! I appreciate the help immensely!!!