# How to split a string of words and add to an array - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string

Let's say I have this:

`NSString *str = @"This is a sample string";`

How will I split the string in a way that each word will be added into a NSMutableArray?

In VB.net you can do this:

```
Dim str As String
    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim count As Integer
    str = "vb.net split test"
    strArr = str.Split(" ")
    For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
        MsgBox(strArr(count))
    Next
```

So how to do this in Objective-C? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c

Comment: I didn't know that "tokenize" is the term used for string split haha. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSArray *words = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```

Note that `words` is returned as an auto-released object, so you might need to `retain` it, unless you are using ARC.

Also, the returned array is not mutable, so you'd need to create one yourself and initialize it with the returned array:

```
NSArray *words = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
NSMutableArray *mutableWords = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[words count]];
[mutableWords addObjectsFromArray:words];
```

or:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableWords = [[str componentsSeparatedByString: @" "] mutableCopy];
```

This last statement returns an object that **must** be released as `copy` gives you ownership of the object.

Comment: What if I want to split the string not only by space, but also by some characters such as comma, period, etc. How will I do this?

Comment: @user1412469 Simply change the `@" "` to `@","` or `@"."` etc.

Comment: No what I mean is, in a single string like this `NSString *str = @"This string is separated by space, comma, and period. How to separate it?"`, how will I do this? Or do you mean that I will repeat the `NSArray *words = [str componentsSeparatedByString: ];` three times, with different components.

Comment: @user1412469 I'm afraid so, however you can use multiple characters in the separator string, for example `@", "`.

Comment: @user1412469 You might be better of separating by space and then stripping leading and trailing commas or dots off each element in the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

There's an inbuilt method on NSString which splits the string based on a set of characters you pass in and returns an NSArray

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

For more, see the [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution. Try it out!

```
NSString *string = @"This is words";
NSArray *wordsArray  = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Lets print the value of wordsArray.

```
NSlog(@"wordsArray value is : %@", wordsArray);
```

Here's the output:

```
wordsArray value is : (
    This,
    is,
    words
)
```