# How to retrieve numbers from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a `NSString` which looks like this `@"1, 5, 23, 15, 6"`. What i need is to retrieve all these numbers from this string. Probably the result might look like an array of NSStrings - `@"1"` , `@"5"`, `@"23"` and so on. How do i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"1, 5, 23, 15, 6";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
```