# How to insert data into my app efficiently?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nsdictionary

I hv a lot of data that format like this:
『 No.1
introduction:
explanation:
Parts1:
Parts2:
..
..
parts8.

No.2
introduction:
explanation:
....
....
....
....
No.100
...
』

I am setting up of my app's model that hold the data as NSMutableDictionary.
So that i can find the data by input a key.

The problem is that there is a lot of data(over 500 sets), Can i have a efficient ways to insert the data without "boring typing"?????

please help.

thank You!^_^"

Comment: Put it in a file.  Read the file?

Answer (score 1):

Create either a JSON file or a [property list file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i) and use the built-in JSON or property list parsing facilities to read the file.  Much better than building your own parser.

Comment: So....How to create that?

Comment: @SteveLai - You mean create the file?  Sometimes you can get a lot accomplished with a text editor and find/replace actions, if you think about it.  Otherwise you may have to just edit in the needed changes, or else write a quick program (eg, in Java or OSx Objective-C) to pre-process the data somehow and take care of part of the editing work.

Answer (score 0):

They way I would approach this problem is to open your file in a text pad and change all the : to pipes |. Now you have a pipe delimited file that you can use to parse.

```
No.1 introduction| explanation| Parts1| Parts2| parts3| (this is on line1)

No.2 introduction| explanation| Parts1| Parts2| parts3| (this is on line2)
```

Now put this file into a string and go over line by line to parse the string. Get each of the values put them in an array and then save the array in your NSDictonary with a key value. I will try to search for some sample code. From here you know

```
array(0) is - No.1 introduction
array(1) is - explanation
...
```

Check this post [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)