# How to split string in iphone programming

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have one `NSMutableArray`in that array I am storing some strings which i got from web service response.in that array strings are:

"Test Test\n  \n  \n    ",
"abc Abc\n  \n  \n    "
"sss Pr\n  \n  \n    ",
"Gggf anil L\n  \n  \n    ",

I want to split strings from \n.now how can i separate strings from \n.
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray * components = [yourString componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"];
for(NSString *str in components)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to trim \n NOT the split.

```
NSString *trimmedValue = [array[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case separating string from \n is BAD programming practice and the process is too much laindy. So better go for trimming string by \n. Try this -

```
NSString *trimmedString = [yourArray[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Hope this will Help you. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This action can be performed in 2 steps.

1 .
   NSArray * seperatedArr1 = [yourString componentsSeperatedByString:@","];

2.
   NSMutableArray *finalArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
   for(NSString *str in seperatedArr1)
   {
       NSString *trimmedString = [finalArr[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
       [finalArr addobject:trimmedString];
   }