# Extract parts of a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a lot of strings looking like this:

```
Soccer Livescore: (POR-SF) #Rio Ave vs #SC Braga: 2-1
Soccer Livescore: (ENG-FC) #Chester FC vs #Halifax: 1-0
```

How can i extract the string between the () and the ints on each side of the -?

Comment: Can you provide more information. 
You can also provide the actual output which you want...
So it will more helpful for us.

Comment: Please check [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer.

```
NSString *string =@"Soccer Livescore: (CONMEBOL-GS) #Rio Ave vs #SC Braga: 2-1";

NSRange range1 = [string rangeOfString:@"("];
NSRange range2 = [string rangeOfString:@")"];
range1.location = range1.location + 1;
range1.length = range2.location - range1.location;


NSString *scoreString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([string length]-3, 3)];
NSArray *scores = [scoreString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

NSLog(@"%@ %d %d", [string substringWithRange:range1], [scores[0] intValue], [scores[1] intValue]);
```

Log result: CONMEBOL-GS 2 1

Comment: This will get the first 6 characters after the (. Can i't be created so it will stop on the ). Cause it could also look like (CONMEBOL-GS) and then the range.length = 6 not work

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wanna look at NSString tokenization: [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)
There is sample in one of the answers there:

```
NSString *string = @"oop:ack:bork:greeble:ponies";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following methods of `NSString`:

[`rangeOfString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) (use it to look for '(' and ')').
[`substringWithRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange%3a) (to get substring 'TM1-TM2').
[`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) (to split string you get by '-' character).