# How to Split a url using substring in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

How do I split a URL by the `/` character?

For example,

```
www.stackoverflow.com/questions
```

I want to split after `/` in the above URL to get `/questions`

Comment: what do you want to do after splitting? make that into 2 separate stirngs ?

Comment: after splitting i want to show the both strings in two labels.

Comment: After splitting i want to show the splitted strings in two labels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks its helpful for me, and how to remove "http://" in before the url.

Comment: How to remove "http://" in prefix of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`pathComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/pathComponents) property on an `NSURL` object.

> This property contains an array containing the individual path components of the URL, each unescaped using the [`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) method. For example, in the URL file:///directory/directory%202/file, the path components array would be @[@"/", @"directory", @"directory 2", @"file"].

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.stackoverflow.com/questions"];
NSString *lastPathComponent = [myUrl lastPathComponent]; // "questions"
NSArray *pathComponents = [myUrl pathComponents]; // <__NSArrayM 0x7fc45b649df0>( www.stackoverflow.com, questions )
```

To remove the `http://`, use [`host`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/host) property:

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions"];
NSString *host = myUrl.host; // stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: @Saravanakumar edited my answer to show how to remove the prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: This answer is not the proper way to do this task. NSURL has all the needed methods to get the various parts of the URL. There is no need to do an string splitting.

Comment: @rmaddy You're absolutely right.  Edited my answer to use the `host` property of an `NSURL`.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you.

```
NSString *url = @"www.stackoverflow.com/questions";
NSArray *items = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSString *str1=[items objectATindex:0];   //www.stackoverflow.com
NSString *str2=[items objectATindex:1];   //questions
```

Comment: I will try your idea, Thanks for answer my question.